# AMQP . Is it a better way to use JWT over certificate based authentication

Tags: jwt, amqp, tls1.2

We are in search of the best possible way to secure our AMQP connection. Our AMQP clients are distributed all around the world and connection to the AMQP server needs to be secure. We are using TLS for the transport level security as recomended by the oasis-open.org . And now looking for the AUTH mechanism for AMQP clients.

One way is to use the same TLS certificate to authenticate the user and SECOND way is to use the new famous JWT as auth mechanism for AMQP. Whenever a client is publishing or subscribing to an AMQP queue, it should get auth by the server by sending the JWT to the server.

Comment: JWT's are issued after the client presents its credentials. What are you using now as credentials in client side? eg: username-password

Comment: What do you mean with  _"We are in search of the best possible way to secure our AMQP connection"_  security, usability, ease of maintenance?

Comment: We are looking for security and ease of maintenance. We have secured the transport layer using the TLS for communication channel security. But still looking for effective authentication mechanism ? Shall we use plain user/passwords or shall we share the certificates for authentication ? If we use certificates then should these be self signed or from CAs like digicert etc.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWT's are issued after the client presents its credentials through the secure TLS channel. The key point here is the authentication mechanism

- **user/password** is easy to use and maintain, but it less secure than using client certificates. User can set a weak password, or lose the post-it where he has annotated.
- **client certificates** require an additional installation on client computer. Stealing a certificate is much more difficult because you can use the system keystore, protect it with password or even use hardware. But certificate distribution is a complex process. You can use your own CA, but you need to consider how are you going to get the certificate to the user and the installation process. Also, the configuration of a two-ways TLS channel will be complex in your client. I think using an external CA is not an option, because each user would need to get a certificate from that CA, and it is a process that you can not control.

Comment: Another approach I came across is to use SASL authentication mechnism with Digest-MD5. I took this from Apache QPID security Guide. https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-0.30/cpp-broker/book/chap-Messaging_User_Guide-Security.html . Is SASL with a good auth mechnism a better approach to avoid complexities of client certificates ? Can u comment on what mechanism is better to use as authentication mechanism for SASL ?

Comment: Reading docs: SASL with Digest-MD5 is basically a user/password mechanism, but sending a hashed challenge with the shared secret (the password) instead of sending the password itself. It would be interesting if you did not use TSL, that protects the channel. In my opinion a user/password mechanism is sufficient in most cases (Google or Facebook use it...)  except if you need a high security level. Then you need to add an extra security factor like client certificates. But generating and distributing certificates is complex. Consider it only if you know how to do it